# SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://ads.google...LineItemService?wsdl' : failed to load external entity

Tags: php, linux, soap, wsdl, google-dfp

I'm trying use Google DFP (Doubleclick for Publishers) Api on my server. I have installed the script and all its dependencies and also I have already set them up. But when I run PHP files in the console, I get this error every time.

> PHP Fatal error: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://ads.goog le.com/apis/ads/publisher/v201611/LineItemService?wsdl' : failed to load externa l entity "https://ads.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v201611/LineItemService?wsdl " in /home/admin/web/glob.space/public_html/src/Google/AdsApi/Common/AdsSoapC lient.php on line 65

Could you please tell me, why this happens? this is a not a code issue, because I use original example codes.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you access the wsdl from a terminal using wget?

Comment: Hi Kris, yes I can.

Comment: The same problem with OrderService. And I also can open the URL in browser, fetch it via wget and even fetch it with file_get_contents and curl in the same php script. Did you find the reason?

Answer (score 1):

just put a slash character between Service and ? in `https://ads.google.com/apis/ads/publisher/v201611/LineItemService?wsdl`

Ref. http://asanamuz.ir/wp/?p=131

Comment: This is wrong. If you put a slash in this case, you request for operation with empty name which does not exist.